# Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I want to upload my web application but getting following error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.   Configuration Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

**Source Error:**

Line 27:         
Line 28:         
Line 29:         
Line 30:         
Line 31:

> **Source File:** C:\Inetpub\vhosts\extremeserverindia.com\olmpusagrotech\web.config
>   Line: 29
>
> **Assembly Load Trace:** The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

**Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1008

web application build in 32bit & our server is 64bit

Comment: Does your bin folder has CrystalDecisions dll?

Comment: Hi @kostasch. - If it doesn't have CrystalDecisions.dll file, how can we add it. (And where can I find this file?)

Comment: @hims056 you need to install crystal reports runtime. you can download it from anywhere. Depending on what version you use download the appropriate runtime.

Comment: Thanks @kostasch. Do you mean like [this one](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27942)?

Comment: You r welcome :) Yes, i mean somthing like this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to download and install ***Crystal Report 13.00 V*** in your System to fix this Error.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify version # of your Crystal Report Run-time in Programs installed on machine, if version number is not matching with version number in error, please install correct version number from [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/), Service Pack 20 for 13.0.2000.0, Service Pack 21 for 13.0.2100.0 and so on. Hope that helps!

[image]